# Force Android Update to Samsung Galaxy S3

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, samsung-galaxy-s-3, updates, 5.0-lollipop, operating-system

My Samsung Galaxy S3 which is on EE's network is currently still running Jelly Bean. Is it possible to push an update through to this, or force install one? If so, how do I go about doing so and what are the risks involved. I would be happy with either KitKat or Jelly Bean.

The device is currently rooted if this would help.

Comment: Have you checked if you can update via "Settings > About Phone > System Updates"?

Comment: @1990clb I have tried this, as the device is rooted they don't give you the option to update

Comment: You could use a custom ROM to update, to 4.4 (Kitkat): http://forum.xda-developers.com/galaxy-s3/development/i9300-to-n00t-bring-lte-fun-to-3g-t2886574/